# How to set component properties in ColdFusion 2016

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-2016

I'm new to ColdFusion and have been experimenting with it. We migrated from Adobe ColdFusion 9 to Adobe ColdFusion 2016 and are now getting the following error.

Inside a component, I'm setting properties to define the multiple databases that I've been using. In ColdFusion 9 it works well. See the image below where the properties are set either in an empty string or a value.

**ColdFusion 9**

[image: ColdFusion 9]

With ColdFusion 2016, the values are undefined. I don't know why is this happening.

**ColdFusion 2016**

[image: ColdFusion 2016]

So when I try to login, this error shows:

[image: Error Description]

I wonder why the values are not being defined in ColdFusion 2016.

Here's a snippet on how I code my component:

```
component output="false" hint="Database Connection Settings" displayname="Datasource" accessors="true" persistent="true"
{
   property name="Datasource";
   property name="itmanagement";
   property name="fixedasset";
   property name="login";
   property name="hris";

   variables.instance = {
       Datasource ="",
       itmanagement="itmanagement",
       fixedasset="wareakay",
       login="login",
       hris="employee_db"
   };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I think, the term "**Datasource**" is a reserved word now. When I change this into another word, my code goes working again.